# Plotting/Mutating Data on R

Tags: r

I've trying to plot data that has been mutated into quarterly growth rates from nominal levels.

i.e the original dataset was

```
Date    GDP Level
2010Q1  457
2010Q2  487
2010Q3  538
2010Q4  589
2011Q1  627
2011Q2  672.2
2011Q3  716.4
2011Q4  760.6
2012Q1  804.8
2012Q2  849
2012Q3  893.2
2012Q4  937.4
```

Which was in an excel file which I have imported using

```
dataset <- read_excel("xx")
```

Then, I have done the below in order to mutate it to quarter on quarter growth ("QoQ Growth):

```
dataset %>%
mutate(QoQ Growth= (GDP Level) / lag(GDP Level, n=1) - 1)
```

I would like to now plot this % growth across time, however I'm not too sure how what the geom_line code is for a mutated variable, any help would be really truly appreciated! I'm quite new to R and really trying to learn, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(QoQGrowth = (GDPLevel) / lag(GDPLevel, n=1) - 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(Date), QoQGrowth, group=1)) +
  geom_line()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2010Q1", "2010Q2", "2010Q3", "2010Q4", 
"2011Q1", "2011Q2", "2011Q3", "2011Q4", "2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", 
"2012Q4"), GDPLevel = c(457, 487, 538, 589, 627, 672.2, 716.4, 
760.6, 804.8, 849, 893.2, 937.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `zoo` defines a S3 class `"yearqtr"` and has a function to handle quarterly dates, `as.yearqtr`. Combined with `ggplot2`'s `scale_x_date`, the formating of quarterly axis labels becomes easier.

```r
dataset <- read.table(text = "
Date    'GDP Level'
2010Q1  457
2010Q2  487
2010Q3  538
2010Q4  589
2011Q1  627
2011Q2  672.2
2011Q3  716.4
2011Q4  760.6
2012Q1  804.8
2012Q2  849
2012Q3  893.2
2012Q4  937.4
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(zoo))
library(ggplot2)

dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.yearqtr(Date, format= "%Y Q%q"),
         Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(`QoQ Growth` = `GDP Level` / lag(`GDP Level`, n = 1) - 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, `QoQ Growth`)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", labels = as.yearqtr) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, that's really good to know; didn't realize that was an option with quarterly dates!

Answer (score 0):

Convert dataset to a zoo object `z`, use `diff.zoo` to get the growth, `QoQ Growth`, and then use `autoplot.zoo` with `scale_x_yearqtr`.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

z <- read.zoo(dataset, FUN = as.yearqtr)
`QoQ Growth` <- diff(z, arith = FALSE) - 1
autoplot(`QoQ Growth`) + 
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", n = length(`QoQ Growth`)) + 
  xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]